# Add cookie for site that redirects in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I need to set login cookies manually in Chrome when testing our site in certain testing environments because the normal login process doesn't work there.

I can get the cookies manually using Postman.

Normally I'd use F12 -> Application -> Cookies but our site immediately redirects you to a our centralized login page (which is on a different domain).

Any idea how to add a cookie to a domain in Chrome if I can't open the domain for long enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EditThisCookie doesn't work for this anymore. I found the easiest approach to be to go to a static resource on the site you're visiting that doesn't redirect you —like the URL of the logo in the login page for example— and set the cookies that way.

Answer (score 0):

I found an extension that allows me to do it, called [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg/related?hl=en). I installed it in a separate Chrome account (just for safety) and then I could add a cookie to a site even when it is not currently opened, thus avoiding the redirect:

[image]